# Spring Doc: swagger-ui.html giving Whitelabel Error Page 404

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am using springdoc-open api for swagger integration in my springboot project.
I have added below property in application.yml

```
spring:
  mvc:
    pathmatch:
      matching-strategy: ant_path_mathcher
```

and added below  dependency in build.gralde file

```
implementation "org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.9"
```

I am able to access /v3/api-docs , but /swagger-ui/index.html and /swagger-ui.html giving 404 Whitelabel Error Page

Comment: Can you please share your @Configuration class?

Comment: Please try `/swagger-ui/` endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After googling so many thins, I found a solution to this issue. I had to add an additional configuration class that is OpenApiConfig.java to make it work.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.springdoc"})
@Import({org.springdoc.core.SpringDocConfiguration.class,
org.springdoc.webmvc.core.SpringDocWebMvcConfiguration.class,
org.springdoc.webmvc.ui.SwaggerConfig.class,
org.springdoc.core.SwaggerUiConfigProperties.class,
org.springdoc.core.SwaggerOAuthProperties.class,
org.springframework.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration.class})
class OpenApiConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
}
```

Comment: Using the lastest version configuration of springdoc-openapi v2.0.4 could be a solution too. https://springdoc.org/v2/